# Where to start in blender?

Tags: modeling, units

I have recently learned all the basics of blender from modeling to rendering, I am little bit confused about where to start 3d designing in blender. please suggest...

Comment: Try with anything, choose the first thing you see as your model.

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'start 3d designing'  do you mean coming up with new 3d objects from an idea, or taking images and making models from them? knowing more about the meaning if your question helps us give better answers / links.

Comment: read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender

Answer (score 1):

best is to pick up a real project. or find a tutorial that guides you to model, texture and render a real project. And here some more ideas:

http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/how-i-learned-blender-and-5-tips-for-you/

http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/5-ways-to-make-money-with-blender/

so if your next question on Blender Stackexchange is about a specific problem then you have started ;)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21980)

Comment: Sorry, but I think I did answer the question. But perhaps you are right, that I should have asked for clarification